# Selenium IDE unable to palyback with FCK Editor text

Tags: selenium, fckeditor, selenium-ide

i am new to selenium and works in a complex project where there is a need to record and playback all modules. So i have a web page with FCK Editor field where user have to enter text. I recorded successfully , but IDE doesnt enters into editor text area to enter any message while play back the test case.

Please help me to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
runScript
CKEDITOR.instances['body'].setData('<p>testContent</p>');
```

change "body" for the name of your ckEditor instance

[image]